# Set environment to production in Authorize.net Python SDK

Tags: python, authorize.net

Can anyone tell me how to switch my environment for a Settled Batch List Request from SANDBOX to PRODUCTION?

I've looked everywhere for documentation and the source code, and the farthest I've gotten is

```
settledBatchListRequest = apicontractsv1.getSettledBatchListRequest()
apicontrollersbase.APIOperationBase(settledBatchListRequest).setenvironment(constants.PRODUCTION)
```

But I still get an 'Invalid Credentials' Error

Comment: When you switched the environment from SANDBOX to PRODUCTION, did you also change your credentials?  Sandbox and production credentials are separate and cannot be used in the other system.

Comment: Yes these are production credentials, I have other sandbox credentials that work if I don't specify an environment.

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely confusing, I ended up looking at the source here:
https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sdk-python/blob/master/authorizenet/constants.py

This should help:

```
>>> from authorizenet.constants import constants
>>> constants.PRODUCTION
'https://api2.authorize.net/xml/v1/request.api'
>>> constants.SANDBOX
'https://apitest.authorize.net/xml/v1/request.api'
```

Ultimately I usually end up setting these in my config files like so:

Production:

```
AUTH_NET_ENVIRONMENT = "https://api2.authorize.net/xml/v1/request.api"
```

Dev:

```
AUTH_NET_ENVIRONMENT = "https://apitest.authorize.net/xml/v1/request.api"
```

Then in your controller:

```
controller.setenvironment(settings.AUTH_NET_ENVIRONMENT)
```

Assuming you are creating the controller correctly, adding this line:

```
from authorizenet.constants import constants
```

or replacing setenvironment(constants.PRODUCTION) with:

```
setenvironment("https://api2.authorize.net/xml/v1/request.api")
```

should work. Hope this helps!

Comment: This solution worked perfectly for me. Before this I was changing line 235 in the `authorizenet/apicontrollersbase.py` from `APIOperationBase.__environment = constants.SANDBOX` to `APIOperationBase.__environment = constants.PRODUCTION`. Which is not ideal but was working.